# Can't use some Rails gems - no such file to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, load, require

I encounter identical issues with some Ruby gems in Rails application.

When I use:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'uuidtools'
```

or

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
```

in Rails application, I get the **"no such file to load -- uuidtools"** error (or **"no such file to load -- json"** - respectively).

- Both gems are installed properly
- When I type these directive pairs in **irb**, **I get "true" as a result**.
- When I try to run application with `rails server` or in a NetBeans debugging session, I get "no such file to load"
- It seems that this issue concerns many of other gems installed.

Comment: No, they were not. I added them and now the application seems to work! By the way, what is the purpose of Gemfile along with installing required gems on "buldle install" command?

Comment: The Gemfile is how `bundle install` knows what to install... its your catalog of dependencies.  In older (Rails < 3.0) apps this was usually managed via config/environment.rb and its cousins). Bundler also 'hijacks' the load path to point it specifically at the dependencies you want, eliminating version problems, but the downside is you can't get by with just `gem install XXX` and have Rails pick it up (though most would argue that's a feature!)

Comment: What are you saying that bundler runs always when the application is running. Did I understand right? Before I've seen your comment I thought that bundler runs and takes control only when you issue a "bundle" command and then finishes.

Comment: Bundler is used by rails to load your gems; the `bundler` command is just a wrapper for that library that puts any binfiles from the correct gem versions in your path, so that you can execute the correct version when multiple are installed. so your previous understanding is incomplete, though not altogether incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added gems to Gemfile and it helped.